# Jupyter notebook canvas not interactive when using %matplotlib inline

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, plot, interactive

I have the following code. Without the line **%matplotlib inline**, jupyter notebook pops out an extra window to display the plot and it is interactive (the right bottom corner updates the x and y values as you move the mouse). With the line **%matplotlib inline**, the plot is not interactive.

Anything I can do to make it interactive within the notebook?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
%matplotlib inline

origins = ['China','Brazil','India','USA','Canada','UK','Germany',
    'Iraq','Chile','Mexico']


df = pd.DataFrame({'height': 
np.random.rand(10),'weight':np.random.rand(10),
              'origin':origins})

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['height'],df['weight'],picker=5)
plt.gca().set_ylabel('Weight')
plt.gca().set_xlabel('Height')

def onpick(event):
    origin = df.iloc[event.ind[0]]['origin']
    plt.gca().set_title('came from {}'.format(origin))

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',onpick)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%matplotlib notebook` instead of `%matplotlib inline`.

As explained in the [IPython tutorial on plotting](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html):

> The matplotlib library also ships with `%matplotlib notebook` command that allows **interactive figures** if your environment allows it.

(Emphasis mine)